# Как отловить все сетевые запросы программы?

Tags: сеть, сниффер

У меня есть программа, которая подключается к сервису и транслирует видео с камеры. Мне надо посмотреть, куда, что и как она отсылает. Пробовал Charles, Wireshark - не смог сделать что хочу. Можете что то еще посоветовать?

Система - Mac OS

Comment: Если не помог Wireshark - почитайте книги по нему.

Comment: может что то посоветуете?

Comment: Поискать "wireshark book" посоветую

Comment: запустил wireshark, включил запись, запустил программу. пощелкал программу, посмотрел в wireshark - ничего нету((